# How to optimize code that changes a value deeply nested in an object graph

Tags: c#, performance, linq

Below is a crude for-loop to illustrate what I need to do.

Basically, if there are any 'Variable' objects with property 'Name' containing the text "TCC#", then I want to change the 'Type' property (not the .Net type) to 'VariableType.Text'.

The code is going to run over 4800 ParsedCard variables and currently takes a stupid amount of time (about 10 minutes) to simply iterate through the list and write a line to the Debug console.

```
ParsedCard has 
IEnumerable functions which have 
IEnumerable groups which have 
ParseResults which have 
IEnumerable variables
```

This is such a simple problem but I've tried all sorts of variations using LINQ but can't find anything that performs well (less than 10 seconds).

```
    private void AdjustTCCVariables(IList<ParsedCard> parsedCards)
    {    
        for (var i = 0; i < parsedCards.Count; i++)
        {
            var parsedCard = parsedCards[i];

            for (var j = 0; j < parsedCard.Functions.Count(); j++)
            {
                var function = parsedCard.Functions.ToList()[j];

                for (var k = 0; k < function.Groups.Count(); k++)
                {
                    var group = function.Groups.ToList()[k];

                    for (var l = 0; l < group.ParseResult.Variables.Count(); l++)
                    {
                        var variable = group.ParseResult.Variables.ToList()[l];

                        if (variable.Name.Contains("TCC#"))
                        {
                            //variable.Type = VariableType.Text;
                            Debug.WriteLine($"Need to change variable at [{i}][{j}][{k}][{l}]");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried with this LINQ but it doesn't actually change the 'variable.Type' of the input list (I suspect because it creates a new copy of the objects in memory and the assignment isn't actually affected the 'parsedCards' IEnumerable at all:

```
    private void AdjustTCCVariables(IEnumerable<ParsedCard> parsedCards)
    {
        var targetVariables =
            parsedCards.SelectMany(x => x.Functions.SelectMany(z => z.Groups))
                .SelectMany(x => x.ParseResult.Variables.Where(v => v.Name.Contains("TCC#")));
        ;

        foreach (var variable in targetVariables)
        {
            variable.Type = VariableType.Text;
        }
    }
```

Comment: could you show us the class defenition of parsedCards

Comment: .ToList() is expensive when it comes to perfomance , what type are theses , parsedCard.Functions , function.Groups , group.Variables

Comment: Your performance issues come from all these `ToList` calls. Why you ever need that? Use simple `foreach` loops. You can use LINQ to get access to the required `variable`s, but it will be essentially the same as using `foreach`.

Comment: I'd try to remove Count() and ToList() by using foreach loops over IEnumerables to start off

Comment: Do you have `class`es or `struct`s?

Comment: All classes - no structs

Comment: What is the actual type behind the `IEnumerable<ParsedCard> parsedCards` variable?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, the bottleneck in your iterations is the `.ToList()` calls.

Since you mention that you only want to edit the `variable.Type` property, I would solve this like this.

```
var variables = from parsedCard in parsedCards
                from function in parsedCard.Functions
                from group in function.Groups
                from variable in group.ParseResult.Variables
                where variable.Name.Contains("TCC#")
                select variable;

foreach (var variable in variables) {
    variable.Type = VariableType.Text;
}
```

You don't need to know anything other than the `variable` objects that need changing, you don't need all the indexes and all the other variables. Just select what you need to know, and change it.

This way you will not know the indexes, so your `Debug.WriteLine(...);` line won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the defintion of the classes , here is some tips.
Remove toList,  dont count on the iteration (for statement)

```
int numberOf = parsedCards.Count
 for (var i = 0; i < numberOf; i++)
        {
            //var parsedCard = parsedCards[i];
            int noOf2 = parsedCard[i].Functions.Count()
            for (var j = 0; j < noOf2; j++)
            {
                var function = parsedCard[i].Functions[j];

                int = function.Groups.Count();
                for (var k = 0; k < noOfGroups; k++)
                {
                    var group = function.Groups[k];
                    int noOfVars = group.ParseResult.Variables.Count();
                    for (var l = 0; l < noOfVars; l++)
                    {
                        var variable = group.ParseResult.Variables[l];
                        if (variable.Name.Contains("TCC#"))
                        {
                            //variable.Type = VariableType.Text;
                            Debug.WriteLine($"Need to change variable at [{i}][{j}][{k}][{l}]");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: But you are assuming they support **indexer**. While all we know from the post is that they are enumerables (because of `Count()` and `ToList()` extension methods defined on `IEnumerable<T>`). So replacing all `for` loops with `foreach` should work.

Comment: yes that would probalby work, but if there is a performance issue with the loop the for-each is a bit slower than this

Comment: That's true, but my point was that you can't safely assume from the OP that the above code will compile. If all these collections are Lists, ok, but why you use `Count()` method and not `Count` property then?

Comment: An old blogpost but it is still actual and covers this issue. http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2008/11/19/an-easy-and-efficient-way-to-improve-net-code-performances/

Comment: This isn't a question of making it 'work' or making it compile...its about performance. I want to significantly reduce the time to iterate the graph and actually EDIT the variable.Type property.

Comment: `for` / `foreach` loop performance comparison has nothing to do with this issue, which apparently is caused by extremely inefficient nested `ToList` calls. Regarding the last comment: slow working code is better than fast non working (if we can consider that way a non compilable) code.

Comment: Ivan, this is a question on a performance issue, high performance code is hardly ever nice to read and whatever it compiles has nothing to do with it considering the information given in the question.

Comment: @Thorarins I understand that. And I'm always for writing a performant code. But you miss my point. We don't know what is the **type** of `Functions`, `Groups` and `Variables` properties and what they hold. You are assuming they are arrays/lists, but imagine they are declared as `IEnumerable<Function>`, `IEnumerable<Group>`, `IEnumerable<Variable`>. So there is no `[index]` accessor. What would you suggest in that case in order to improve the performance?